# Передача методу агрументов

Tags: java, переменные, методы

Пишу класс, в котором есть метод (acceptSelection), принимающий пользовательский ход в виде строки типа "А3", "В4" и тому подобное. В этом методе происходит отделение символа от числа. В итоге получаются четыре переменные : word1, number1, word2, word2, которые являются строковыми и числовыми представлениями пользовательского хода соответственно. То есть , допустим, были ходы А3 и В4 , значит word1="A", word2="B", number1=3, number2=4. После этого необходимо определить их индексы в массиве из метода (getScore).

```
public class ExampleOne {

    private static int number1;
    private static int number2;
    private static String word1;
    private static String word2;
    private static int index1;
    private static int index2;
    private static String a3 = "A3";
    private static String b4 = "B4";

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        acceptSelection(a3, b4); 
        System.out.println("Index 1 " + index1);
        System.out.println("Index 2 " + index2); }

    public static int getScore (String df, int b) {

        int totalScore=0;

        if (a=="A") {

            totalScore = (0+b)-1;
            //return totalScore;

        }

        else if (a=="B") {

            totalScore = (4+b)-1;
            //return totalScore;
        }

        else if (a=="C") {

            totalScore = (8+b)-1;
            //return totalScore;
        }

        else if (a=="D") {

            totalScore = (12+b)-1;
            //return totalScore;
        }

        else if (a=="E") {

            totalScore = (16+b)-1;
            //return totalScore;
        }

        else if (a=="F") {

            totalScore = (20+b)-1;
            //return totalScore;
        }

        else if (a=="G") {

            totalScore = (24+b)-1;
            //return totalScore;

        }

        return totalScore;

    }

    public static void acceptSelection (String a, String b) {

        Pattern number = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
        Matcher m = number.matcher(a);
        Matcher m1 = number.matcher(b);

        while (m.find()) {

            number1 =Integer.parseInt(a.substring(m.start(), m.end()));

        }

        while (m1.find()) {

            number2 =Integer.parseInt(b.substring(m1.start(), m1.end()));

        }

        Pattern word = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
        Matcher w = word.matcher(a);
        Matcher w1 = word.matcher(b);

        while (w.find()) {

            word1 = a.substring(w.start() , w.end());

        }

        while (w1.find()) {

            word2 = b.substring(w1.start() , w1.end());

        }

        index1 = getScore(word1, number1);
        index2 = getScore(word2, number2);
    }
```

При вызове метода getScore таким способом index1 = getScore(word1, number1), возвращается нулевое значение totalScore. Однако, если вызвать метод таким образом: 
index1 = getScore("A", 3)
все работает правильно. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Кажется, что проблема кроется в простом, просто не вижу.

Comment: дак я понимаю, что он не соответствует  условиям, но я и спрашиваю почему это условие не проходит? При тестировании переменных способом вывода на консоль, работает правильно. Если в методе я вывожу через prinln переменную word1, на консоль выводится правильная строка.

Comment: Ставите точку останова в начале. Включаете код в режиме отладки. Смотрите по шагам как работает ваша программа. Ищете ошибки. Profit

Comment: Строки сравниваются через оператор `equals()`, а не `==` : например `a.equals("A")` - так будет работать, но я бы вам рекомендовал полностью переработать весь этот код, он ужасен (ничего личного)

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Насчет когда учту. Если есть какая то литература по этому поводу  - подскажите.

Comment: Любые учебники по Java от признанных авторов: Б.Эккель, Г.Шилдт, К.Хортсманн ..

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю то же самое, но несколько попроще.

**UPD**: и еще несколько проще:

```
public class ExampleOne {

    private static String a3 = "A3";
    private static String b4 = "B4";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Index 1 " + acceptSelection(a3));
        System.out.println("Index 2 " + acceptSelection(b4));
    }

    public static int getScore(char ch, int num) {

        int code = (int)ch;
        return  (code-65)*4+num-1;
    }

    public static int acceptSelection(String str) {

        char word = str.charAt(0);
        int number = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(1));
        return getScore( word, number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно. Спасибо большое, протестирую)